# Get rid of "caption=" in log file

Tags: batch-file

Currently also putting the operating system in the logfile, I'm using the following command (which suits best my needs):

```
wmic os get caption /value | find "Caption=" >>c:\log.log
```

The output in the log will be:
Caption=Microsoft Windows 7 Professional

Is there a way I can delete the "Caption=" from the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `/value` you can filter the non needed lines with `findstr`

```dos
wmic os get caption | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^Caption" >> c:\log.log
```

Or with `/value` you can filter the output with a `for /f` command splitting the line in the equal sign

```dos
( 
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic os get caption /value') do echo %%a
) >>c:\log.log
```